# Dynamic changes on a web page without refresh

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I wanted to know if there is a way to tackle this problem:

I have a mysql database, and when a student logs in there is a table that inserts the student entry into the database.
Now there is a web page which shows the currently logged in students in that table.

When a new entry is inserted it should automatically update the table. I had thought of using simple function calls that would solve some of my issues.

Now let a.php be the page from where the student logs in and from where I make the call to insert query `function(insert_new_data())`. Let b.html be the page where I always display the contents in that table.

I wanted to know that how can I handle this situation where, when a new entry is added to the database I have to call a function that would update the table shown in b.html.

Currently what I am doing is calling a `function(update_table())` inside `insert_new_data()` which creates a new table (and which is replaced using `document.getElementByID("some_id").innerHTML)` and calls for select query which populates
it with new data;
but how do I transfer the control to b.html so that I can see the changes on that page, without using polling and refreshing the page. I am not even sure if this is possible.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated...

Comment: It would help to split your text into paragraphs. This bunch of continuous text is hard to read.

Comment: The answer is probably Ajax. Here is jQuery's flavour of it: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

This question borders on the concept known as [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). What you are asking for is a a data push from the server to the client. There are some great [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) frameworks available. Many AJAX frameworks have [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) functionality. However, making use of Comet - or some other HTTP push technology - is IMHO overkill if you are only using it on a single web page.

If there the page you are creating is not going to be used by thousands of concurrent users, then I would go with the polling option.